# Show that there exists unique real solution

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

Show that there exists unique real numbers $a$ and $b$ satisfying
$$3\sin a-2\cos b=6a-12,$$
$$\cos a + 3\sin b=6b+6.$$
Thank you!

Comment: No thoughts? No ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: I have found this problem in the "Metric Spaces" by Mícheál Ó Searcóid (http://books.google.com/books?id=aP37I4QWFRcC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=3sina%E2%88%922cosb%3D6a%E2%88%9212&source=bl&ots=wDQsxO8BE6&sig=WfCr7_fn4Wnlkr650f6vP7Ql2aA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DhwTUrcn5bDKAcLkgNgH&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=3sina%E2%88%922cosb%3D6a%E2%88%9212&f=false ) question number 10.11 (in completeness theme). But there is no solution for this exercise at the end of the book. And I still have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Hint: Mr. [Banach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) might know the answer... if you ask him the right question!

Answer (score 0):

The existence of a solution can be shown by looking at the two $(a;b)$ curves solving the equations.

The first equation implies a positive $a$.
Its implicit plot looks like:

[image]

The second equation implies a negative $b$:

[image]

Both curves intersect in one point $(a > 0;b < 0)$.

Asking the `Excel Solver`, I get:

$a = 2.36505619$
$b = -1.61785965$